# Not able to dynamically disable Bootstrap button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a way to disable a Bootstrap button dynamically based on a Model value. I've tried the following with no luck. All I get is the default values of a Bootstrap button.

```
<button type="submit" class=@((Model.employeeId > 0) ? "btn btn-primary" : "btn btn-primary disabled")>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit
</button>
```

AND

```
@{ 
    var cssClass = "btn btn-primary";
    if (Model.employeeId == 0)
    {
        cssClass = "btn btn-primary disabled";
    }
} 

<button type="submit" class=@cssClass>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit
</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried enclosing your class in quotes?  `class='@cssClass'`?  As written it probably will be malformed html and might only take `btn` as the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the disabled attribute? It would be something like the following.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @((Model.employeeId > 0) ? "" : "disabled = 'disabled'")>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit
</button>
```